# What suitable locking technique to prevent insertion of data? [PostgreSQL]

Tags: postgresql

I want to ensure that **one** worker has exactly **one** manager

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_relationships (
  object_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY               NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  manager_id INT REFERENCES users (object_id) NOT NULL,
  worker_id  INT REFERENCES users (object_id) NOT NULL,
  CHECK (manager_id != worker_id),
  UNIQUE (manager_id, worker_id)
);
```

I have series of SQL statements using Read Committed level of transaction isolation,

```
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=manager_id AND acc_type="manager" FOR UPDATE;
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id=worker_id AND acc_type="worker" FOR UPDATE;
SELECT * FROM relationships WHERE id=worker;
INSERT INTO relationships (m, w) VALUES (manager_id, worker_id)
COMMIT
```

- I have figured out the first two **FOR UPDATE** to prevent other
  concurrent transactions from changing the users account type mid
  transaction
- I could not figure out what kind of "trick" to use for third query. Third query should return empty list to ensure that the worker has not yet been owned by any manager.
- Third query **FOR UPDATE** does not work because I am expecting an empty row.
- Due to third query, I run the risk of concurrent transaction adding duplicate worker to different managers.

What can I do to enforce one worker to one manager?

Comment: @VaoTsun `(1,2)` and `(2,2)` would be considered non-unique, but the worker 2 would have two managers which is what Zanko tries to prevent

Comment: IC it now. If that object_id would not be there, unique(manager_id) and unique(worker_id) would do the trick?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you need to add UNIQUE to constraint to worker_id:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS user_relationships (
  object_id  SERIAL PRIMARY KEY               NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  manager_id INT REFERENCES users (object_id) NOT NULL,
  worker_id  INT REFERENCES users (object_id) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
  CHECK (manager_id != worker_id)
);
```

But is better to add field `manager_id INT REFERENCES users (object_id) NOT NULL` to table `users` and do not use `user_relationships`.

Comment: Thank you! I failed to see such a simple solution!